# Something wrong with the background:@drawable/img

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a beginner in Android. I just have written my code and when I insert my picture on `LinearLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` like this:

```
android:background=@drawable/myimage
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.nanda.kosku/com.example.nanda.kosku.DetailBangunanActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XMLfile line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
```

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsinglayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
    app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:title="App Title"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: I have done with this issue. I change size of the image and keep .png extension. It's WORK for me! I think, my image's size before too large and android studio know it as useless image.

If you have same issue as me, try to resize your image :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following under the `dependencies` section of your `build.gradle` file inside app.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    comple 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

    //... Other dependencies
}
```

And the final layout should look like this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/collapsinglayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
    app:title="App Title">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. But i still get that error :( i have confused with this error. Only this image that make my app error like this image can't use anymore even i try to make it again with new file :(

Comment: What is the file extension of your image?

Comment: .png sir. And i was changed it into .jpg and then .png again. There is still that error :(

Comment: Have you tried different image in this layout and found everything okay?

Comment: Yes, i have. There is no error if i change it with another image. I don't know why. But thank you to trying help me sir :)

Comment: Then you might have some problems with the image. However, I am still confused in this case. Upload the image to any online image converted and then convert it to .png and then try with the converted image.